# 405 - REST - verb used to access path with dots is not allowed

Tags: wcf, rest

I have a WCF REST interface with `UriTemplate="Action/{object}"`. This interface works fine on `IIS`, but on the `ASP.NET development host`, it is giving me `405`, e.g., `The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/x.svc/Action/a.b.c' is not allowed.` In the debugger, I reach `Application_BeginRequest` before it fails.

I don't have an issue for `{object}` values that don't contain a dot.

From what I've found, it appears this is a conflict with routing rules. It is as if the `UriTemplate` is conflicting with a higher priority rule that looks at the `URI` as a file path.

Is there a way to get the ASP.NET Development Server to behave the same as `IIS`?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get the ASP.NET Development Server to behave the same as IIS?

You could use [`IIS Express`](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx) instead of Cassini. It will behave exactly the same as the full blown IIS server. You might need to move all your http modules and handlers to the `<system.webServer>` section if you switch to IIS express.